# What Exactly Causes Lunar Nodal Precession?

Tags: the-moon, solar-eclipse

I'm trying to understand what exactly causes lunar nodal precession.

Based on [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_precession), my understanding is that precession of the plane of the moon's orbit is what causes the motion of the Moon's nodes along the ecliptic. Is this a correct understanding? Thinking more deeply about it, it seems that Apsidal precession could also impact the location of the nodes, but I would imagine this motion would have a smaller effect.

[image]

Comment: From [my answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/40923/16685), "The torque caused by the Earth trying to pull the Moon into an equatorial orbit causes the nodal precession". Robjohn has some nice anims of nodal precession [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/47674/16685).

Comment: We normally consider the Moon's nodal and apsidal precessions separately. They have different periods, and opposite rotation directions.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful responses @PM2Ring! After reviewing these links, what I'm not quite following yet is why the torque caused by the Earth trying to pull the Moon into an equatorial orbit would lead to *periodic motion* - is there something I’m missing? My understanding after reviewing Robjohn’s animations is that the earth’s torque causes the plane of the lunar orbit to basically wobble, leading to nodal precession - is that a fair characterization? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that's fair. The Earth-Moon system orbiting around the EMB (Earth-Moon barycentre) precesses like a gyroscope. I have more info & diagrams here:  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/47503/16685